# PostgreSQL: get all children from a join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT u.name, d.title, c.name
FROM documents d 
INNER JOIN publications p ON p.document_id = d.id
INNER JOIN components c ON p.component_id = c.id
INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id
```

My problem is that this only returns the first `c.name` when `documents` can have many `components` through `publications`. I need something to iterate through each `document` and get **all** their `publications`, then fetch the title through each publication's component.

I've tried a with statement like so:

```
WITH child_publications AS (
    SELECT c.name, c.id
    FROM publications p
    INNER JOIN components c ON p.component_id = c.id
)
```

But I'm not quite certain how to wield them. Publications looks like this:

```
    Column    |  Type   |                         Modifiers                         | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer | not null default nextval('publications_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 document_id  | integer |                                                           | plain   |              | 
 component_id | integer |                                                           | plain   |              |
```

Components like this:

```
            Column             |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                            | integer                     | not null default nextval('components_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name                          | character varying           |                                                         | extended |              | 
 body                          | text                        |                                                         | extended |              |
```

Documents like this:

```
        Column         |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 message               | text                        |                                                        | extended |              | 
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null                                               | plain    |              | 
 updated_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null                                               | plain    |              | 
 title                 | character varying           |                                                        | extended |              | 
 user_id               | integer                     | not null                                               | plain    |              |
```

The column names are representative of what data they hold, I'm not sure what DDL is.

Comment: please provide more details (DDL and sample data)

Comment: Hope that helps?

Comment: Oh. Step into our place (answerers), what would you do with this data? DDL (`CREATE ...`) would be much easier to consume and would speed up answering significantly.

Comment: But it's okay, the structure is clear now, what about data?  There is nothing wrong with your JOINs and they should return multiple "components" per each document/publication, but smth is not correct with data and relations between entities, I suspect. Please provide data.

Comment: (DDL stands for "data definition language" -- it's an abbreviation used to name `CREATE`, `ALTER ...` and other commands changing the structure)

Comment: Ah right, this is from a Rails app so they'd be like migrations, I need to find a way to rewrite them, one moment.

Comment: Now what is more important is data.
Actually, you can use pg_dump with `-t` option to choose particular table (you can place multiple `-t` in single command: `pg_dump -U username databasename -t documents -t publications -t components -t users`), then edit output to hide what you want to hide and if it's big, publish somewhere like pastebin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INNER JOINS restrict the result to only those rows that meet ALL join conditions. An OUTER JOIN removes that and allows ALL ROWS FROM documents (in this query). The most common outer join is the LEFT OUTER JOIN as used below:

```
SELECT u.name, d.title, c.name
FROM documents d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN publications p ON p.document_id = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN components c ON p.component_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id
```

The "downside" to this is you may get NULLs in the result now.

"OUTER" is optional in SQL syntax, so you could use the following, and it would be the same result:

```
SELECT u.name, d.title, c.name
FROM documents d 
LEFT JOIN publications p ON p.document_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN components c ON p.component_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id
```